# Gradle unable to detect external dependency in another project

Tags: java, gradle

I have a multi-project gradle project with the following structure when running

> gradle projects

The CommonUtils is a standalone project while Interceptor uses CommonUtils.

```
Root project 'main-project'
+--- Project ':CommonUtils'
+--- Project ':Interceptor'
\--- Project ':SearchService'
```

When running gradle build in main-project, I encountered this error:

```
Task :Interceptor:compileJava FAILED
```

In IntelliJ, I noticed it could not detect these 2 imports:

1. import com.google.gson.Gson;
2. import com.rometools.rome.feed.rss.Channel;

The build.gradle for CommonUtils is:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.0.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
bootJar{
    enabled=false
}
jar{
    enabled=true
}
ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR1")
}

processResources {
    def profile = (project.hasProperty('profile') ? project.profile : 'local').toLowerCase()
    include "**/"
    rename "bootstrap-${profile}.properties","bootstrap.properties"
    include "bootstrap.properties"
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.13.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:2.2.0.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    implementation platform('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:1.11.755')
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticsearch'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:1.11.847'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib:1.0.4'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:2.2.0.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20160810'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.13'
    implementation 'com.oracle.ojdbc:xmlparserv2:19.3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'
    implementation group: 'com.github.dozermapper', name: 'dozer-core', version: '6.5.0'
    implementation group: 'com.github.dozermapper', name: 'dozer-spring-boot-starter', version: '6.5.0'
    implementation group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itext7-core', version: '7.1.10', ext: 'pom'
    implementation group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'html2pdf', version: '2.1.7'
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation group: 'io.micrometer', name: 'micrometer-registry-elastic', version: '1.1.4'
    implementation 'com.rometools:rome:1.18.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    implementation 'rome:rome:1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    runtimeOnly('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

The build.gradle for Interceptor is:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.0.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
bootJar{
    enabled=false
}
jar{
    enabled=true
}
dependencies {
    implementation project(':CommonUtils')
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.5'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the failed dependency in the Interceptor project? You can either change the problematic dependencies in CommonUtils to be `api` instead of `implementation` which would let them be accessible from the Interceptor project or you can add them again to the Interceptor project.